# Differentiation terminology

Tags: terminology

In $ \frac{d}{dx}y $, what is the name of the variable being respected in this differentiation? Is there a general term for the variable in $ \frac{d}{dx}y $, $ \frac{d}{dt}v $, and others that can be used to refer to the $ x $ and $ t $? As I always phrase it in the way that "A value is being differentiated with respect to $ x $", the only term I can think of is "respected value".

Comment: As far as I know, you call $x$ the independent variable, that is, you don't introduce any special name for $x$ in $dy/dx$, because you don't need to rename things that after all already have a name.

Comment: Oh, of course! That's perfect, thanks! (I only needed a more general term to refer to the variable in my notes)